# How to return the text from an asp button by clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can return the backgroundColor from this function but not the text or innerText.  I have about 100 buttons of which I want to pick both the background color and text when clicked on.  I don't want a function for each button.

`var c` shows in the alert so I know the alert is working but `var iT` is blank.

I've tried it with both Chrome v51~ and IE11.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function () {
        var b = document.getElementById(document.activeElement.id);
        var c = b.style.backgroundColor;
        var iT = b.innerText;
        alert(c + " " + iT);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you google innerText, the property you're having problems with?  The first hit says "it's non-standard, don't use it" and offers suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide your html so that we can see what's going on. Are you sure you need `innerText`, not `innerHTML`?

Comment: If your "buttons" are `input type="button"` or `input type="submit"` then "text" is `value` attribute. If `<button...>something</buttom>` then `innerHTML`.

Comment: yes James, I did research it and found what you said above,  but out of about 50 tries nothing else did it either, color easy, text, not so much.   Alex, tried every kind of text out there, as well as innerHTML and innerText, no soap!  Thank you, YakovL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.my-button').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this)
    var color = btn.css('backgroundColor')
    var text = btn.text() || btn.val() // if text is inner html tag, or on value attribute
    alert(color + " " + text);
  });
})
```

With a link

```
<a class="my-button">Click me</a>
```

With button

```
<button class="my-button" value="Click me"/>
<input type="submit" class="my-button" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, the above returns the rgb color number but no text value, and it must be specified for one particular button as opposed to all buttons.  I'll play with it and see what I can come up with, thanks again.

Comment: thanks, got this working too with your help.  der, how do I mark the question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Use the attr() function in jQuery to get the value of the button:

```
alert($(this).attr("value"));
```

Comment: Cause you don't have `value` attribute on your button. Work with `<button value="test" />`